# Android - how to pass view coordinates to surface view coordinates

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, zxing

In my app I have scanner view, which must scan two barcodes with zxing library. Top barcode is in PDF417 format, bottom  - in DATAMATRIX. I used https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner as a base, but with main difference: I have to use image coordinates as scan area. Main algorithm:

1. Depends of current step, scan activity passes current scan area to scanner view in screen coordinates. These coordinates calculated as follows:

`public static Rect getScanRectangle(View view) {
        int[] l = new int[2];
        view.measure(0, 0);
        view.getLocationOnScreen(l);
        return new Rect(l[0], l[1], l[0] + view.getMeasuredWidth(), l[1] + view.getMeasuredHeight());
    }`

2.In the scanner view, in onPreviewFrame method, camera preview size is received from camera parameters. When I translated byte data from camera to bitmap image in memory, I saw, that it rotated 90 degrees cw, and camera resolution not equals screen resolution. So, I have to map screen coordinates into camera (or surface view) coordinates:

```
private Rect normalizeScreenCoordinates(Rect input, int cameraWidth, int cameraHeight) {
    if(screenSize == null) {
        screenSize = new Point();
        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        display.getSize(screenSize);
    }
    int height = screenSize.x;
    int width = screenSize.y;
    float widthCoef = (float)cameraWidth/width;
    float heightCoef = (float)cameraHeight/height;
    Rect result = new Rect((int)(input.top * widthCoef), (int)(input.left * heightCoef), (int)(input.bottom * widthCoef), (int)(input.right * heightCoef));
    return result;
}
```

3. After that, translated coordinates passes into axing and on most test devices all works fine. But not on Nexus 5X. First, there are serious gap between display size and activity.getWindow().getDecorView() sizes. Maybe this is related to status bar size, which is translucent and for some reason it's height maybe not calculated. But, even after I added vertical offset, there are something wrong with scan area. What's may be reason for that error?